# How to add mark in google maps with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, marker

I have this , which is working perfectly:

```
<div id ="map"   style="width: 304px; top: 68px; left: 172px; position: absolute; height: 238px">
```

Ad my Javascript code:

```
function InitializeMap()
{
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.452692, -56.3972349, 17, 15);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
}
window.onload = InitializeMap;
```

I found this code for adding a marker. How can I integrate it with my already written code?

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker(
{
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.8, 77.03),
     map: myMap,
     title: 'New Delhi'
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put it at the end of your `InitiallizeMap` and change `map: myMap` to `map: map`.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
function InitializeMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.452692, -56.3972349, 17, 15);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(28.8, 77.03),
        map: map,
        title: 'New Delhi'
    });
}
window.onload = InitializeMap;
```